# For loop to get first letter from an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

Hi so I need to have this program print all the countries who's first letter matches the letter the user inputs.

I am currently having trouble with the for loop as it does not let me run it at all and it looks like this

```
        for (String s1: countries) {
                if (countries.startsWith(input))
                System.out.println(s1); 
            }
```

This is how my program looks like until now (I don't know but maybe it helps...)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    String input;

    //Creating the Array
    String countries[] = {"Germany", "Switzerland", "Japan", "USA", "Ghana", "Saudi Arabia", "Uganda", "Russia", "Romania", "Great Britain", "Urugai", "Etheopia", "Ecuador", "Estonia", "Egypt", "France", "Austria", "Australia", "Argentinia", "Afganistan", "Albania", "Syria", "Turkey", "India", "Iraq", "Iran", "Angola", "Congo", "South Africa", "Somalia", "Madagascar", "Mexico", "Chile", "Venezuela", "Cuba", "Vietnam", "Cambodia", "Nepal", "Pakistan", "Khazakstan", "Turkmenistan", "Peru", "Namibia", "Czech Republic"};

        //User Input
        System.out.println("When you enter the letter, you will get to know all the countries in our array starting with this letter.");
        input = s.next();

        //finding and printing the countries with the users letter as their first letter
        for (String s1: countries) {
                if (countries.startsWith(input))
                System.out.println(s1); 
            }

}
```

}

Comment: Follow the link to the dupe, then inside the loop use `if (country.startsWith(input))`

Comment: Use s1 in place of country in for (String s1: countries) { if (s1(input)) System.out.println(s1); }

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
for (String country: countries) {
    if (Character.toString(country.charAt(0)).equals(input)) {
        System.out.println(country);
    }
}
```

We iterate through each country and if the first character is equal to input. The `charAt` returns a character which we have to convert to String before comparing it to `input`.

You might also want to check if the `country` String has any characters at all.

Comment: country is a `String`, not an `Array`, thus `country[0]` means nothing. Perhaps you wanted to use `country.charAt(0).equals(input)`

Comment: You can't access characters in a string like that.in Java

Comment: country is not a list

Comment: Thanks, it's fixed.

Comment: It's not "fixed" terrible. See my comment to question.

Comment: `input` could be a word, but the user only wants to compare the first character.